# The meaning and usage of "к кому-либо клинья подбивать"

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> Он уже и **к** **тебе** **клинья подбивал**, верно?

Considering that they are talking about a ladykiller, I assume this phrase essentially means "try to seduce someone", but I'm not sure how to interpret "клинья подбивать" literally. Can the perfect "подбить" be used as well?

Comment: found out that the idiom is also used with the preposition **под** *кого-л.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiom doesn't always mean romantic interest, though that is the most common usage. It can be used as a substitution for "trying to gain favor with" in any situation, for example, with a boss at work. It also colors the attempt (of gaining favor) as obvious, and is most often used ironically, to poke at a person doing this.

Answer (score 2):

The idiom is **подбивать клинья** used mostly with the imperfect form showing the process of courting. Perhaps the perfective form can be used in the infinitive.

> Ну, что, не удалось тебе к ней клинья подбить? (Rare)
>
> Смотри-ка, так и вьется вокруг нее, клинья подбивает.

It's a colloquial idiom meaning "courting"

As for a literal meaning, It's "to drive a wedge", a sharp triangle piece of wood.

Comment: Hi. What about its more literal meaning?

Comment: "To strike a wedge", compare https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD

Comment: ...with the undertone of *fitting* the wedges, too.

Comment: I added the literal meaning

Comment: Interestingly enough, "drive a wedge" in English means a completely different thing: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/drive-a-wedge-between-sb?q=%2Bdrive%2Ba%2Bwedge

Comment: @"Con-gras-tue-les-chiens yes, it's odd even in Russian, because phrase "вбить клин" ("to drive a wedge", very similar to English) is more common than aforementioned "подбивать клинья".